# Result of x % 10 in Java

Tags: java

could anyone tell me what  is the output of (x modulus 10) in java; if x is a positive integer number from 1 (inclusive) to 9 (inclusive) ? I wrote this code to see what it could be but got nothing:

```
   for(int i=1;i<10;++i)
    {
      int y = (i%10);
      System.out.println("y is:" + y);
     }
```

Comment: How come you got nothing? Where are you having that code?

Comment: did you run it? what was your output like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test Java code and don't have access to a development environment, you can still use a public service like ideone.com. I did that for you [over here](http://ideone.com/CTJQtJ). Your program prints

```
y is:1
y is:2
y is:3
y is:4
y is:5
y is:6
y is:7
y is:8
y is:9
```

Answer (score 2):

You should go this output:

```
y is:1
y is:2
y is:3
y is:4
y is:5
y is:6
y is:7
y is:8
y is:9
```

basically if you have `y % x` and `0 <= y < x` the  `y % x = x`.
Otherwise, `y % x = y - ( y / x)`.

Answer (score 2):

X%10 , read as x modulo 10, gives the remainder of the operation x/10.

I.e.

For eg:

```
If x=11

Then x%10 =1

If x=1

Then x%10 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**For integer `x` the result of `x % 10` is an integer between `-9` and `9` (both inclusive).**

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3):

> The binary % operator is said to yield the remainder of its operands
>   from an implied division; the left-hand operand is the dividend and
>   the right-hand operand is the divisor.
>
> In C and C++, the remainder operator accepts only integral operands,
>   but in the Java programming language, it also accepts floating-point
>   operands.
>
> The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary
>   numeric promotion (§5.6.2) produces a result value such that
>   (a/b)*b+(a%b) is equal to a.
>
> This identity holds even in the special case that the dividend is the
>   negative integer of largest possible magnitude for its type and the
>   divisor is -1 (the remainder is 0).
>
> It follows from this rule that the result of the remainder operation
>   can be negative only if the dividend is negative, and can be positive
>   only if the dividend is positive. Moreover, the magnitude of the
>   result is always less than the magnitude of the divisor.